# How can I remove a clickable bar with hyperlink in each page of a pdf file?

Tags: pdf

Can we remove a long narrow clickable bar(with some hidden text and link) at the bottom of each page of [this pdf file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13029929/new2.pdf)? When never I click it, it will tries to open a website in my browser.

I prefer to do that from command line, because there may be a pdf file with more pages with such bars.

I tried https://superuser.com/a/536644/9265, but it only can remove the text in the bar, and the bar and the hyperlink still exist.

Thanks.

Comment: Please reupload the example pdf file. I might have a more elegant solution. A very simple python script using pdfrw lib.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not expert of `pdf` format, but from your example file I believe the unwanted parts are objects `17`, `33` and `49`. To remove those objects I would use `pcregrep` in the following way:

```
pcregrep -aMv '(17|33|49) 0 obj(.|\n)*?Hello(.|\n)*?endobj' new2.pdf > new3.pdf
```

Here `-a` option is needed to treat binary file as text, `-M` to match multiline and `-v` to invert match.

After that you will still need to repair the new file as described in the answer linked in your question (https://superuser.com/a/536644/9265).

Comment: Thanks. How do you find out "the unwanted parts are objects 17, 33 and 49"?

Comment: @Tim I've opened your file in `less` and searched for `Hello`. Then looked around for the some tags.